# ORACLE exibindo campo data com 1 dia a mais no final dos meses com 31 dias

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, datetime, pl-sql

Criei uma função no ORACLE para calcular a data da última parcela passando como parametro a quantidade de parcelas e usando a função ADD_MONTHS(DT_PRIM_PARCELA, PARCELAS).

Porém, se passo uma data por exemplo ADD_MONTHS('30/11/2020, 96 - 1), a data da última parcela deveria ser dia (30/10/2028), no entanto, o ORACLE está retornando (31/10/2028).

Isso está ocorrendo sempre que a data da última parcela cai em uma mês com 31 dias.

Isso é padrão do ORACLE ou é alguma questão de configuração?

```html
SELECT D.NR_PROSPECT,
       D.DT_PRIM_PARC,
       D.PRAZO,
       ADD_MONTHS('30/11/2020', 96 - 1) AS DATA_ULT_VENCIMENTO
  FROM TB_PROSPECT_CREDITO D
 WHERE NR_PROSPECT = 1490;
```

Comment: Tenta o seguinte: `SELECT LEAST(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('30/11/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),96), ADD_MONTHS(to_date('30/11/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')-1,96)+1) as foo FROM DUAL;`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions077.htm#SQLRF00654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A própria documentação da função [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) cita:

> if date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has
> fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last
> day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day
> component as date

Traduzindo, se a data é o último dia do mês ou mês resultante tiver menos dias que a data passada, então o resultado será o último dia do mês. Caso contrário o resultado terá o mesmo dia.